# Application does not appear anymore in Facebook Search Box

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-page

I had an application on production, ~900 MAU, linked with a fan page. **Through the Facebook search box, anyone could find the application typing its name.** Note that the Fan page and the application have the same name.

Recently (2 weeks ago), **I had to change the application "Display name"** with something totally different, and since that day, **the search box does not find our application anymore**. Note that the fan page has not been updated, so the title is still the old name.

I've probably missed something in the documentation, but it looks like if an app is linked with a fan page, the Facebook search box uses the fan page's name & descriptions for the application itself.

Can someone confirm?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been experienced by me much times that some stuff (Pages/Events/Apps) don't appear at the search box. A friend suggested giving it some time to update and it worked. Probably it's the same problem, it just needs some time to be cached

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I waited 2 weeks and only the application developpers can see it in the search box. Do you have any idea of how long we've to wait?

Comment: Not really :| You have to contact their support then, or check your app's settings

Comment: It seems it works now for some users. As you explained, it needed some time to be cached. Thank you.

Comment: No problem :) That happens with lots of people.

Good luck with your app :) And an up-vote won't cost you much :D